# Why ConditionVariable in Ruby does not work as expected?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

I have problems in understanding how Mutex and Condition variable work in Ruby.
Here is my code:

```
mutex = Mutex.new
cv = ConditionVariable.new

Thread.new  {
  puts 'First: Hello'

  cv.signal
}

 Thread.new  {
  cv.wait(mutex)

  puts 'Second: Hello'

}

Thread.new  {
  cv.wait(mutex)

  puts 'Third: Hello'
}

sleep 1
```

and it results in

```
First: Hello
```

I've tried to use `cv.broadcast` but it didn't change anything. Also I've tried to delete third thread and make it work only with threads and it also didn't change anything. So, could someone explain how  to make two threads wait until another thread signals?

Comment: `sleep 1` is bad code. That is fragile. You should never use time-related code to control multiple threads.

Comment: @sawa it's used only for giving time time threads to finish, in general I use thread.join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to work inside a synchronization block of the mutex (`mutex.synchronize do ... end`)
2. If the first thread runs first, it might finish before the other threads `wait`, so they won't get the signal.
3. `signal` wake up one thread, so the other threads should also signal when they finish to wake the next thread

So, try to change your code to something like this:

```
mutex = Mutex.new
cv = ConditionVariable.new

Thread.new  {
  sleep 1
  mutex.synchronize do
    puts 'First: Hello'

    cv.signal
  end
}

Thread.new  {
  mutex.synchronize do
    cv.wait(mutex)

    puts 'Second: Hello'
    cv.signal
  end
}

Thread.new  {
  mutex.synchronize do
    cv.wait(mutex)

    puts 'Third: Hello'
    cv.signal
  end
}

sleep 1
```

Comment: I've tried using mutex.synchronize, and the result changed. But your code some times returns output from one thread and sometimes output is from all of threads. Generally output is unpredictable

Comment: The thing is, that cv.wait does not make threads wait for signal. And I don't understand why

Comment: Your explanation about mutex synchronization is correct, but your code does not work as you wrote. It is still possible for `cv.signal` to be executed before `cv.wait(mutex)`.

Answer (score 1):

After some time of struggling, I've understood what the problem  was. It's all about condition  variable taking lock. I don't if my code is correct, but it shows runs sequentially.

```
cv = ConditionVariable.new
mutex = Mutex.new

mutex2 = Mutex.new
cv2 = ConditionVariable.new

mutex3 = Mutex.new
cv3 = ConditionVariable.new

mutex4 = Mutex.new
cv4 = ConditionVariable.new

mutex5 = Mutex.new
cv5 = ConditionVariable.new

mutex6 = Mutex.new
cv6 = ConditionVariable.new



Thread.new do
  mutex.synchronize {
    puts 'First: Hi'
    cv.wait(mutex)
    puts 'First: Bye'
    #cv.wait(mutex)
    cv.signal
    puts 'First: One more time'
  }

end

Thread.new do
  mutex.synchronize {
    puts 'Second: Hi'
    cv.signal
    cv.wait(mutex)
    puts 'Second:Bye'
    cv.signal
  }

  mutex2.synchronize {
    puts  'Second: Starting third'
    cv2.signal

  }
end

Thread.new do
  mutex2.synchronize {
    cv2.wait(mutex2)
    puts 'Third: Hi'
  }

  mutex3.synchronize {
    puts 'Third: Starting forth'
    cv3.signal
  }
end

Thread.new do
  mutex3.synchronize {
    cv3.wait(mutex3)
    puts 'Forth: Hi'
  }

  mutex4.synchronize {
    puts 'Forth: Starting fifth'
    cv4.signal
  }
end

Thread.new do
  mutex4.synchronize {
    cv4.wait(mutex4)
    puts 'Fifth: Hi'
  }

  mutex5.synchronize {
    puts 'Fifth: Starting sixth'
    cv5.signal
  }
end

Thread.new {
  mutex5.synchronize {
    cv5.wait(mutex5)
    puts 'Sixth:Hi'
  }
}

sleep 2
```